# Разделение родителей-потомков по уровням

Tags: php, рекурсия

Имеется такой массив в php, для удобства перевел в json:

```
[
  {
    "id": "5b6176820eccd3089f46bb2f",
    "parent": "5b61645b0eccd36d4f768982"
  },
  {
    "id": "5b61767a0eccd36d4f768a7d",
    "parent": "5b6164500eccd3662d487833"
  },
  {
    "id": "5b6164660eccd35e20608ab5",
    "parent": "5b61645b0eccd36d4f768982"
  },
  {
    "id": "5b61645b0eccd36d4f768982",
    "parent": "5b6164500eccd3662d487833"
  },
  {
    "id": "5b6164500eccd3662d487833",
    "parent": "5b604c360eccd350c016fdc2"
  },
    {
      "id": "5b6176820eccd3089f46bb3z",
      "parent": "5b61767a0eccd36d4f768a7d"
    },
    {
      "id": "5b6176820eccd3089f46bb4g",
      "parent": "5b61767a0eccd36d4f768a7d"
    },
  {
    "id": "5b604c360eccd350c016fdc2",
    "parent": 0
  }
]
```

Нужно перевести по уровням, вот так:

```
{
  "level-1": [
    {
      "id": "5b604c360eccd350c016fdc2",
      "parent": 0
    }
  ],
  "level-2": [
    {
      "id": "5b6164500eccd3662d487833",
      "parent": "5b604c360eccd350c016fdc2"
    }
  ],
  "level-3": [
    {
      "id": "5b61645b0eccd36d4f768982",
      "parent": "5b6164500eccd3662d487833"
    },
    {
      "id": "5b61767a0eccd36d4f768a7d",
      "parent": "5b6164500eccd3662d487833"
    }
  ],
  "level-4": [
    {
      "id": "5b6164660eccd35e20608ab5",
      "parent": "5b61645b0eccd36d4f768982"
    },
    {
      "id": "5b6176820eccd3089f46bb2f",
      "parent": "5b61645b0eccd36d4f768982"
    },
    {
      "id": "5b6176820eccd3089f46bb3z",
      "parent": "5b61767a0eccd36d4f768a7d"
    },
    {
      "id": "5b6176820eccd3089f46bb4g",
      "parent": "5b61767a0eccd36d4f768a7d"
    }
  ]
}
```

Мои попытки:

```
foreach ($groups as $key => $group) {
    if($group['group_id'] === 0) {
        $tree[0][] = $group;
    } elseif ($group['group_id'] !== 0) {
        $level = 1;
        $level = $this->findGroupLevel($level, $group['group_id'], $flatGroups);
        $tree[$level]][] = $group;
    }
}


public function findGroupLevel(int $level, string $groupId, array $groups)
{
    $found = array_search($groupId, array_column($groups, 'parent'), true);

    if( $found !== false ) {

        if($groups[$found]['parent'] !== 0) {
            $level++;

            return $this->findGroupLevel($level, $groups[$found]['parent'], $groups);
        }
        return $level;
    }

    return null;
}
```

Comment: Если у двух элементов в одном блоке есть наследники, тогда как очерёдность последующих блоков выстраивать?

Comment: В представленном примере только один элемент из блока level-3 имеет наследников

Comment: Очередность не важна, главное чтобы по уровням было все правильно

Comment: что вы называете очередностью, а что уровнем?

Comment: В пределах (или внутри) уровня (level-x), сортировка элементов не важна. А в целом, элементы должны быть раскиданы по уровням правильно, как в примере выше

Comment: Как раскидывать "level-x" если 2 элемента в блоке имеют наследников, а не только один как в примере выше?

Comment: Перекидывать на следующий уровень, очевидно же, сейчас исправлю пример

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Перебираем значения и для каждого рекурсивно определяем число родителей. Уровень - это число родителей + 1.

```
$in = [
    ["id" => "5b6176820eccd3089f46bb2f", "parent" => "5b61645b0eccd36d4f768982"],
    ["id" => "5b61767a0eccd36d4f768a7d", "parent" => "5b6164500eccd3662d487833"],
    ["id" => "5b6164660eccd35e20608ab5", "parent" => "5b61645b0eccd36d4f768982"],
    ["id" => "5b61645b0eccd36d4f768982", "parent" => "5b6164500eccd3662d487833"],
    ["id" => "5b6164500eccd3662d487833", "parent" => "5b604c360eccd350c016fdc2"],
    ["id" => "5b6176820eccd3089f46bb3z", "parent" => "5b61767a0eccd36d4f768a7d"],
    ["id" => "5b6176820eccd3089f46bb4g", "parent" => "5b61767a0eccd36d4f768a7d"],
    ["id" => "5b604c360eccd350c016fdc2", "parent" => 0]
];

$out = [];
foreach ($in as $k => $v) {
    $level = 1 + getParentsCount($v["parent"], $in);
    $out["level-{$level}"][] = $v;
}
ksort($out);
var_export($out);

function getParentsCount($parent, &$in)
{
    if ($parent === 0) {
        return 0;
    }
    foreach ($in as $k => $v) {
        if ($v["id"] === $parent) {
            return 1 + getParentsCount($v["parent"], $in);
        }
    }
    throw new Exception("Ссылка на несуществующего родителя с id = '{$parent}'");
}
```

У меня получился такой результат:

```
[
  'level-1' => [
    ['id' => '5b604c360eccd350c016fdc2', 'parent' => 0],
  ],
  'level-2' => [
    ['id' => '5b6164500eccd3662d487833', 'parent' => '5b604c360eccd350c016fdc2'],
  ],
  'level-3' => [
    ['id' => '5b61767a0eccd36d4f768a7d', 'parent' => '5b6164500eccd3662d487833'],
    ['id' => '5b61645b0eccd36d4f768982', 'parent' => '5b6164500eccd3662d487833'],
  ],
  'level-4' => [
    ['id' => '5b6176820eccd3089f46bb2f', 'parent' => '5b61645b0eccd36d4f768982'],
    ['id' => '5b6164660eccd35e20608ab5', 'parent' => '5b61645b0eccd36d4f768982'],
    ['id' => '5b6176820eccd3089f46bb3z', 'parent' => '5b61767a0eccd36d4f768a7d'],
    ['id' => '5b6176820eccd3089f46bb4g', 'parent' => '5b61767a0eccd36d4f768a7d'],
  ],
]
```

Answer (score 1):

```
/**
 * @author Oleg Isaev
 * @contacts vk.com/id50416641, t.me/pandcar, github.com/pandcar
 */

$class = new AJRecursion($array);
$class->run(['0']);

print_r($class->result);

class AJRecursion
{
    public  $data = [],
            $result = [];

    public function __construct($data = [])
    {
        $this->data = $data;
    }

    public function run($ids = [])
    {
        $tmp = [];

        foreach ($ids as $id) {
            $keys = array_keys(array_column($this->data, 'parent'), $id);

            foreach ($keys as $key) $tmp[] = $this->data[$key];
        }

        if (empty($tmp)) return false;

        $this->result['level-'.(count($this->result) + 1)] = $tmp;
        $this->run(array_column($tmp, 'id'));
    }
}
```